# In Metal Shading Language (MSL), how do I write pass-by-reference functions generic over address space?

Tags: gpgpu, metal, compute-shader

I'm writing a `Foo` class for a Metal compute shader and want users to be able to add `Foo`s regardless of the address space in which they reside. If I take the values by reference, this means I have to declare many permutations of which address spaces things live in:

```cpp
class Foo {
private:
  uint8_t bunchOfData[160];

public:
  operator+(const thread Foo&) const thread;
  operator+(const constant Foo&) cosnt thread;
  operator+(const thread Foo&) const constant;
  operator+(const constant Foo&) const constant;
  // ... More overloads for local. For device, users should manually unpack to maintain coalescing.
}
```

1. Is there a way to genericize the address space qualifiers using templates?
2. Should I just use pass by value and dodge this whole problem entirely?

- The size of Foo is non-trivial, like 160 bytes each.
- When I last wrote compute kernels (i.e. 2009 era OpenCL), GPUs couldn't make function calls so pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference didn't really make a difference since everything got inlined anyways. Is this still the case?

3. If pass-by-reference is still useful, is it conventional to simply have the caller copy the value into `thread` space and only provide the thread-thread variant?

I've tried writing:

```cpp
class Foo {
private:
  uint8_t bunchOfData[160];

public:
  template <typename T> operator+(const T& rhs) const;
}
```

but this gives me the error

```
error: reference type must have explicit address space qualifier
      template <typename T> operator+(const T& rhs);
```

Not that I'm even specifying the address space of `this` correctly anyways...

Comment: For part 2, I changed the references to values and benchmarked the result. This resulted in a 20% slowdown, so I believe it does make a difference.

Comment: You would need to write several different template functions, probably with the same code in them, because templates don't really work over the qualifiers as you expect them too.

Answer (score 0):

Pass by reference vs pass by value is definitely relevant unless the optimiser can deduce what you're trying to do. (Which it might if your class uses the default copy constructor, etc.) In any case, unnecessarily copying 160 bytes per thread is likely a measurable overhead. The Metal compiler will still aggressively try to inline function calls, but modern GPUs definitely support "real" function calls - including function pointers!

Templating on address space qualifier is tricky. There's no special syntax for parameterising the address space on its own. Frustratingly, it *is* possible to parameterise the type referenced but to pin the address space:

```
template <typename T> void do_foo(threadgroup T* my_t);
```

At least in my experience, it's much less common to want to do that than to allow the address space to be flexible.

Overloading works as you might expect for function signatures that differ only in the address space of their pointer or reference arguments. At minimum, this means you can provide an implementation for each kind of address space you care about, but at the cost of duplication.

With some template trickery however, we *can* write functions that take a pointer to a specific type with *any* address space:

```cpp
// define these once:
template <typename CHECK_T, typename TARGET_T> struct is_ptr_to;
template <typename T> struct is_ptr_to<thread T*, T>
{
    static constant const bool value = true;
};
template <typename T> struct is_ptr_to<threadgroup T*, T>
{
    static constant const bool value = true;
};
template <typename T> struct is_ptr_to<device T*, T>
{
    static constant const bool value = true;
};

// function where INT_PTR may be any of thread int*, threadgroup int*, or device int*.
// choose/vary: --vvvvvvv-------------------------------vvvvvvv--vvv
template<typename INT_PTR, metal::enable_if_t<is_ptr_to<INT_PTR, int>::value, bool> = true>
    void set_1(INT_PTR a)
{
    *a = 1;
}
```

It's not pretty, but it does work. (Perhaps someone who is better at templates can come up with something more compact; or you could wrap it in a macro.)

Unfortunately, you can't do the exact same thing with reference types, as the ambiguity between by-value and by-reference in function templates is resolved to pick by-value; and as soon as you insert an ampersand in the argument declaration, the Metal compiler complains the address space is missing. All the workarounds I've tried have required either explicit template instantiation parameters or helper functions for wrapping arguments. (I do hope someone manages to prove me wrong, however.)

As a sort of hybrid solution, you could implement the core logic as an internal template function which accepts suitably constrained **pointer** arguments, then create a bunch of 1-liner wrapper functions which accept each combination of **reference** arguments you want to support, which just forward the call to the pointer version. Or the implementation function could expect reference arguments, while the wrappers explicitly instantiate it with the correct reference type template arguments.